# Chaining jquery template appendTo method

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Is it possible to chain the appendTo method of jQuery template like this:

```
 $("#total-costs-template").tmpl({ CurrentMortgage: vm.currentMortgage, Products: products }).appendTo("#total-costs-analysis").find("#total-costs-month").click(function () {

                        alert('test');

                    });
```

I remember doint it before but in the above code it's not working, I dont get an error either though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

```
$(a).appendTo(b)
```

returns a jQuery object that's equivalent to `$(a)`